# Unity inputs not working

Tags: unity-game-engine, input, scroll

I am using Unity 5.5 and i have created a basic UI based scene. I am facing problem with inputs in the sense that scroll rect or any key inputs are not firing ( i am printing logs in update) but the click events from buttons are working properly.

The methods Input.GetKey or Input.GetKeyDown are not working at all.

Please can someone help me identify the problem.

Comment: `void Update()
    {
        //Debug.Log("update called");
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            print("key pressed");
            ShowMainPanel();
        }
    }`

Comment: I explored the problem further ..I am using more than one panel and want to make them look like a book...The input is working on first panel...it fails on second panel(when the first one is rotated sideways)

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned in your comment, it seems like you have other object on top of your items that is blocking the raycasts. You can use Canvas Group and set BlocksRayCasts to false and interactable to false in the top object so it lets the beneath objects get the clics.